# Place text blow the spinner image

Tags: css

I have a spinner using **img** tag.Using css style for spinning the image.Existing **CSS** are given below

```
.rotate {
  animation: rotation 9s infinite linear;
  top: 390px;
  left: 665px;
  width: 111px;
  height: 120px;
}

.spinnerlogo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 42px;
  height: 48px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

I am trying to add a text just below the rotate style.

Added below style for that.it wont work and image showing at the right side.

```
.rotate p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

**html code given below**

```
<div>
    <div *ngIf="isLoading" class="spinner-wrapper">
        <img alt="rotate" src="img.svg" class="rotate">   
        <img alt="spinnerlogo" src="img.svg " class="spinnerlogo">
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Is there any way to solve this issue.
did i miss anything from the above code.
please suggest

Comment: `.rotate p` selects every paragraph that is a child of an element with rotate class. Your rotate class is on the image, which can't have have any children. So your CSS does not have any effect.

Comment: @cloned How to solve this

Comment: Start by learning the basics of css and how selectors Work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a diagram or a better explanation of what you want, it's pretty hard to help you. As others said in the comments, your style rule for the paragraph won't work as-is, so just add a class to the paragraph and create style rules for that class.

If you add a snippet to your question, that will help enormously too. Try running this one. Now we can all see what your code does, and hopefully now you can now use this to describe for us what you actually want to do.

```css
.rotate {
  animation: rotation 9s infinite linear;
  top: 390px;
  left: 665px;
  width: 111px;
  height: 120px;
}

.spinnerlogo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 42px;
  height: 48px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

.sometext {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div *ngIf="isLoading" class="spinner-wrapper">
        <img alt="rotate" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Fidget_spinner.svg" class="rotate">   
        <img alt="spinnerlogo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Fidget_spinner.svg" class="spinnerlogo">
        <p class="sometext">text</p>
    </div>
    
</div>
```